# Need to adjust this

Tags: excel, vba

Someone from my company created this code to automatically change data within a spreadsheet. I wrote a question yesterday on here and asked about this same thing.

I think this is the code that I need to use but I need it to compare column G to F. How would I write this code to do that?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-4]-RC[16])/RC[-4]*100" 
       -- This code compares column G to column C. 
          I need it to compare column G to F.
```

Thank you for taking the time to help me. I know nothing about code.

Comment: You could just use the macro recorder here to get the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you've given does not compare column G to column C: it compares column -4 with column 16, based on the cell where you currently are (the so-called `ActiveCell` in your code). This means that the difference between both columns is 20 columns, which is larger than the difference between G and C (e.g. I would rather go for columns W and C).

In fact, your formula calculates the procentual difference between the mentioned columns (from -4 to 16), e.g.

```
In column -4, value 5.
In column 16, value 6.
The result of your formula will be 20 (from 5 to 6, there is an increase of 20%).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()
Dim Check as Boolean
'Call the function, on the row you want 

Check = Compare_Rng(1) 'Or any other integer value it will return True if same and False if not

End Sub

Private Function Compare_Rng(RowCnt as Integer) as Boolean

If Sheets("Sheet Name").Range("G" & RowCnt) = Sheets("Sheet Name").Range("F" & RowCnt) Then  
Compare_Rng = True
Else
Compare_Rng = False
End if

End Function
```

If You want to insert formula you can do this by below

```
    Dim RowNr as Integer
    RowNr = ActiveCell.Row
    ActiveCell = "=G" & RowNr & "=F" & RowNr
```